# Outlook CRM plugin not syncing cases properly

Tags: outlook, microsoft-dynamics-crm

We have CRM 2011 on premise.

One of our users sees more cases in the Active Cases view in Outlook than they do in the Active Cases view in Internet Explorer. The Active Cases view is unmodified from the default. This has been going on for a few weeks.

All his synchronisation settings look ok. There are no errors in the CRM eventlog on his machine.

How can I investigate?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @JamesWood So which site is it most suitable for?